# IOS Testing: KIF vs Instruments/Automation

Tags: ios, testing

Which one would you recommend for functional testing? I am familiar with the specifications of both. What I want is to hear your opinions and experiences with these testing kits. Right now I am leaning towards using Instruments/Automation because it's Apples own. Seems more lightweight to write this in js than in obj-c.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are a developer, I'd recommend Instruments automation. KIF is good and all, but it could take lot of time to write a simple testcase. Also Instruments/ UI automation comes with Xcode so it is pretty simple and doesn't require to make modifications to your project.

Comment: Which did you choose to use? How did it go?

Comment: So what do you recommend to developers (and from a 2015 perspective)?

Comment: I just started out with Automation again. This time it works :). Not without problems, but anyhow.

Comment: Here's an article discussing the tradeoffs: http://appleprogramming.com/blog/2014/02/07/ios-ui-automated-testing-tools/